# How to replace indexing caused by groupby()

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I want to replace the `groupby()` Column names from the `PassengerId` that I have now . I understand that this is caused by my `groupby()` function .

Is there an alternate way to accomplish this table as it is with the column names as i want it ?

**Doubt_indexing :**

[image]

Comment: [Don't post images of code (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Post the code itself.

Comment: I not sure what you want, but please try `df.index.name='...'` or `df.columns = ['...', '...']`

Answer (score 2):

you can use `keys` parameter to set the name of columns:

```
titanic_merged_sex_df = pd.concat([titanic_data_group_sex_df, titanic_survived_group_sex_df],
           axis=1,
           keys=['PassengerId_left', 'PassengerId_right'])
```

Comment: There is no need for `'\'` at the end of the line inside a function call.